# EF4 - Can a POCO be used as both an Entity and ComplexType?

Tags: entity-framework-4, entity-framework-ctp5, complextype

I am using EF4 CTP5.  Here are my POCOs:

```
public class Address
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Line1 { get; set; }
    public string Line2 { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
    public string State { get; set; }
    public string PostalCode { get; set; }
}

public class Customer
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<Address> Addresses { get; set; }
    public List<Order> Orders { get; set; }
}

public class Order
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public decimal Total { get; set; }
    public Address ShippingAddress { get; set; }
    public Address BillingAddress { get; set; }
}
```

Is there a way to get Address to be a ComplexType for the Order class?  After playing around with this, I'm guessing not, but maybe there's a way I haven't seen.

**EDIT**: In response to Shawn below, I gave it my best shot:

```
//modelBuilder.Entity<Order>().Ignore(o => o.BillingAddress);
//modelBuilder.Entity<Order>().Ignore(o => o.ShippingAddress);
modelBuilder.Entity<Order>()
    .Property(o => o.BillingAddress.City).HasColumnName("BillingCity");
```

Fails at runtime with error ***"The configured property 'BillingAddress' is not a declared property on the entity 'Order'."***  Trying to use `Ignore()` doesn't work.  Next, the Hanselman article is CTP4, but the CTP5 equivalent is:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Order>().Map(mapconfig =>
{
    mapconfig.Properties(o => new {
        o.Id
        , o.Total
        , o.BillingAddress.City
    });
    mapconfig.ToTable("Orders");
});
```

Fails with error ***"Property 'BillingAddress.City' of type 'Order' cannot be included in its mapping."***

I give up.  Maybe the final release will have something like this.  Or maybe I need to switch to NHibernate =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need to do is to place `ComplexTypeAttribute` on Address class:

```
[ComplexType]
public class Address
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Line1 { get; set; }
    public string Line2 { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
    public string State { get; set; }
    public string PostalCode { get; set; }
}
```

Alternatively, you can achieve this by fluent API:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.ComplexType<Address>();
}
```

But you *cannot* have Address type as to be both an Entity and a Complex Type, it's one way or another.

Take a look at this blog post where I discuss this at length:

[**Associations in EF Code First CTP5: Part 1 – Complex Types**](http://weblogs.asp.net/manavi/archive/2010/12/11/entity-association-mapping-with-code-first-part-1-one-to-one-associations.aspx)

Comment: If I declare modelBuilder.ComplexType<Address>();, what happens to my List<Address>?

Comment: As of your current setup, it will be ignored but if you try to establish an association based on it (either by fluent API or even by adding a navigation property like Customer to the Address class) then EF will throw and remind you that Address is a Complex Type and cannot participate in FK associations.

Comment: I've tried some of Shawn's suggestions, and have added them to my post.  Let me know if you can think of any other 'hacks.'  (By the way, I have an open question here, and I'd like to hear your input: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4703378/ef4-independent-associations-why-avoid-them)

Comment: Like I said, you cannot use a class as an entity and a complex type at the same time, period. There are no "hacks" or workarounds for this.

Answer (score 0):

If you want `Address` to be in the same table as Order, you're going to have to tell EF that in the DbContext OnModelCreating override.

Take a look here: http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/07/23/entity-framework-4-code-first-custom-database-schema-mapping.aspx

Comment: I made some attempts (see my edits to the main post), but I don't think you are correct.  Have a look and let me know if you have any suggestions.